# Change rake test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my job we have a development, test and production environments.  Development is the local environment use for development, test is a shared environment use for general purpose testing (QA) and production is well for production.

We are starting to development is Rails, in this framework the 'test' environment is use for running the specs.  How do we specify the  new environment to run the unit tests?

I have try to change the value of RAILS_ENV on "test_helper" but when running "rake test" it still try to connect to the test database.

Comment: do not change the environment for tests. it violates all the conventions, that are set up for the gems you use.

Comment: if you just want to change database from test to development, you can just specify it in database.yml